# User-Defined function with data table aggregation

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I'm attempting to write a function majorly with aggregations/merge/subset data sets. My data frame looks like:

```
NameA   NameB   NameC   Score1   Score2
  A       F       K       3         3
  B       F       L       5         5
  C       F       M       7         4
  D       G       N       2         2
  E       G       O       5         8
```

and the function I will run is:

```
test <- Fun(data, Score1, NameB)
```

First, I want to calculate the mean of Score1, grouped by NameB:

```
Fun <- function(df, col, group_by){
       setDT(df)
       df1<- df[, sapply(.SD, mean),  .SDcols = col, by= group_by]
    }
```

After some extra coding, My data frame turns to be:

```
NameA   NameB   NameC   Score1   Score2   Group_Mean
  A       F       K       3         3          4
  B       F       L       5         5          4
  C       F       M       4         4          4
  D       G       N       2         2          5
  E       G       O       5         8          5
```

Then, I want subset my data frame with Score1 != Score2. So I write:

```
Fun <- function(df, col, group_by){
       setDT(df)
       df1<- df[, sapply(.SD, mean),  .SDcols = col, by= group_by]           
       df2 <- df1[which(df1[col] != df[Score2])]
}
```

but this gives me an error message as : 
`Error in Ops.data.frame(df2[col], df[Score2]) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`

After this step, I want to do some more math and subset as below:

```
Fun <- function(df, col, group_by){
       setDT(df)
       df1<- df[, sapply(.SD, mean),  .SDcols = col, by= group_by]           
       df2 <- df1[which(df1[col] != df[Score2])]

       df2["NewCol"] <- abs(df2[col] - df2[Score2])
       output <- df2[which(df2[NewCol] > 1 or df2[NewCol] < 1.5)]
       return(output)
    }
```

I'm new to R and R user-defined function. After the error message part, I'm stuck for a long time. Please, if anyone is able to give me any suggestions on my code above, I would be really appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is your expected output?

Comment: It is not clear where `Master_Table`.is used.  2) Use `lapply` i.e. `df[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = col, by = group_by]`;  3) `df[Score2]` may not give what ever you expected it to do, 4) similar porblem with `NewCol' and the `or` should be `|`

Comment: You've got some typos. Your `Fun` takes an input `col`, but then you start using `col1` which is never defined. Also you'll to better always using `,` inside `[` for selecting data table columns, and using `with = FALSE]` if it's a string column name `df[, col1, with = FALSE]`

Comment: Much appreciate for your help! I've fixed the typo and hope it gets clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is wise to encourage an R novice to enter a wild mix of `data.table` syntax and function calls.

However, here are some sample functions.

```
library(data.table)

data <- fread(
  "NameA   NameB   NameC   Score1   Score2
  A       F       K       3         3
  B       F       L       5         5
  C       F       M       7         4
  D       G       N       2         2
  E       G       O       5         8"
)

Fun1 <- function(df, col, group_by){
  setDT(df)[, sapply(.SD, mean),  .SDcols = col, by = group_by]
}
Fun1(data, "Score1", "NameB")
```

> ```
>    NameB  V1
> 1:     F 5.0
> 2:     G 3.5
> ```

Note that `Score2` is used in the next example to reproduce OP's depicted dataframe:

```
Fun2 <- function(df, col, group_by){
  setDT(df)[, Group_Mean := mean(get(col)), by = group_by]
}
Fun2(data, "Score2", "NameB")[]
```

> ```
>    NameA NameB NameC Score1 Score2 Group_Mean
> 1:     A     F     K      3      3          4
> 2:     B     F     L      5      5          4
> 3:     C     F     M      7      4          4
> 4:     D     G     N      2      2          5
> 5:     E     G     O      5      8          5
> ```

Example 3:

```
Fun3 <- function(df, col, group_by){
  setDT(df)[, Group_Mean := mean(get(col)), by = group_by]
  df[get(col) != Score2]
}
Fun3(data, "Score1", "NameB")[]
```

> ```
>    NameA NameB NameC Score1 Score2 Group_Mean
> 1:     C     F     M      7      4        5.0
> 2:     E     G     O      5      8        3.5
> ```

Note that the function below has been modified WRT to OP's draft in order to return a non-empty data.table

```
Fun4 <- function(df, col, group_by){
  setDT(df)[, Group_Mean := mean(get(col)), by = group_by]
  df[, NewCol := abs(get(col) - Group_Mean)]
  df[between(NewCol, 1.0, 1.5, incbounds = TRUE)]
}
Fun4(data, "Score1", "NameB")[]
```

> ```
>    NameA NameB NameC Score1 Score2 Group_Mean NewCol
> 1:     D     G     N      2      2        3.5    1.5
> 2:     E     G     O      5      8        3.5    1.5
> ```

Note that `data` has been modified `in place` by all previous function calls

```
data
```

> ```
>    NameA NameB NameC Score1 Score2 Group_Mean NewCol
> 1:     A     F     K      3      3        5.0    2.0
> 2:     B     F     L      5      5        5.0    0.0
> 3:     C     F     M      7      4        5.0    2.0
> 4:     D     G     N      2      2        3.5    1.5
> 5:     E     G     O      5      8        3.5    1.5
> ```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! I didn't think about this approach before, it definitely helps me!